# Can't load source properly unless refresh in debug mode Cordova iOS project

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, promise

I am trying to initialize a bluetooth central in Cordova iOS project via . a plugin from [this github](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle). My code looks like below:

-www

index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
        //initialize the Bluetooth adapter
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
          new Promise(function (resolve) {
                bluetoothle.initialize(resolve, { request: true, statusReceiver: false });
              }).then(initializeSuccess, handleError);
          });
    },
/* rest part is just the Cordova helloword template*/
};

app.initialize();
```

/ServiceS/BLEService.js

```
function initializeSuccess(result) {

    if (result.status === "enabled") {

        log("Bluetooth is enabled.");
        log(result);
    }

    else {

        document.getElementById("start-scan").disabled = true;

        log("Bluetooth is not enabled:", "status");
        log(result, "status");
    }
}

function handleError(error) {

    var msg;

    if (error.error && error.message) {

        var errorItems = [];

        if (error.service) {

            errorItems.push("service: " + (uuids[error.service] || error.service));
        }

        if (error.characteristic) {

            errorItems.push("characteristic: " + (uuids[error.characteristic] || error.characteristic));
        }

        msg = "Error on " + error.error + ": " + error.message + (errorItems.length && (" (" + errorItems.join(", ") + ")"));
    }

    else {

        msg = error;
    }

    log(msg, "error");

    if (error.error === "read" && error.service && error.characteristic) {

        reportValue(error.service, error.characteristic, "Error: " + error.message);
    }
}

function log(msg, level) {

    level = level || "log";

    if (typeof msg === "object") {

        msg = JSON.stringify(msg, null, "  ");
    }

    console.log(msg);

    if (level === "status" || level === "error") {

        var msgDiv = document.createElement("div");
        msgDiv.textContent = msg;

        if (level === "error") {

            msgDiv.style.color = "red";
        }

        msgDiv.style.padding = "5px 0";
        msgDiv.style.borderBottom = "rgb(192,192,192) solid 1px";
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(msgDiv);
    }
}
```

and index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>                
            </div>
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Services/BLEService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically everything here are just the startup code getting from the Cordova helloword and the github of that bluetooth plugin. I tried to build up the project in XCode and everything works fine so far. No error for build and run on device.

Than after I run the project directly on my phone, there is no response whether the initialize success or fail. I do get the message in the Output in xcode indicate "Received Event: deviceready" though. So I think it is just the part of "promise" javascript wasn't work. Than I link the debugger from safari and use the developer tool over there. If I click the refresh manually over there, by the next time the application is reloaded on the phone, I do can see the "Bluetooth is enabled" and {"status": "enabled"} in the output now.

But I have no clue why all the functions in the promise just will not be loaded in the first time. Do anyone have any clue on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I end up this whole thing with actually understand the .m part of this plugin. On the cordova-plugin-bluetoothle github up to 2017/12/11, if you look into the BluetoothLePlugin.m line 664, when you initial the centralManager, the first time you initialize it, it will not return whether enabled or disabled. Only you recalled it a second time, you will be able to see the "enabled" feedback. Therefore, I changed my code in the index.js to following:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
          //the reason following function be called twice is, the plugin is designed like this
          //(check BluetoothLePlugin.m line 664 and after)
          //first time this function will intialize the centralManager, but will not check whether it is enabled or not
          new Promise(function (resolve) {
                      bluetoothle.initialize(resolve, { request: true, statusReceiver: false });
                      }).then(initializeSuccess, handleError);
          //for the second time it will check if it's enabled or not
          new Promise(function (resolve) {
                      bluetoothle.initialize(resolve, { request: true, statusReceiver: false });
                      }).then(initializeSuccess, handleError);
          });
```

And it work as I expected after. I am considering to report this interesting "feature" to the author to see if this weird solution is due to my misunderstanding or what.